# Need to get all elements ending with specific text in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have some elements on my page which have xpath like `//*[@id='protect']/a`, `//*[@id='deezer']/a` ,`//*[@id='international']/a`..I want to get all the xpaths in an array list..all the xpaths are ending with '/a'..but the id is different for all the elements..please help
i want to get all the elements in an array list.so that i can click them by using some loops and conditions inside loop

Comment: If you only interested in a-elements so you can just select them all e.g. //a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a straighforward way to do it in selenium: using findElements. Ex:

```
List list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
```

You'll get every single hyperlink on the page stored in a List. Then you'll be able to handle every webelement in it by using loops.

Comment: I think i didnt post my question correctly..these elemnts are buttons..the solution you gave will all get all the links..i dont want to do that..the xpaths are //[@id='protect']/a, //[@id='deezer']/a ,//*[@id='international']/a..i want only these three elements for example..

Comment: Ok. Then you shall find out the similarities between your elements. If you post the html code I can help you further. Or you can tryList list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));

Comment: Sorry I misclicked, didn't finish, comment coming soon

Comment: Ok. Then you shall find out the similarities between your elements. If you post the html code I can help you further. Or you can try this if your list of ids isn't too long:   

List list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'protect') or contains(@id, 'deezer') or contains(@id, 'international')]/a"));

Let me know if it solves your problem!